# jqTransform dropdownlist change not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using jqtranform to transform my form elements, which works very nice.

Recently, I had to add some script to handle the change event on my dropdownlist:

```
$("#@Html.IdFor(i=>i.CurrentIdea)").change(function () {
     var dropdown = $("#@Html.IdFor(i=>i.CurrentIdea)");
     var url = "/Idea/Dashboard/" + dropdown.val();
     window.location = url;
});

@Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.CurrentIdea, new SelectList
   (Model.IdeasList, "Id", "Name"), new { @style = "width:300px;" })
```

Whenever I change the dropdownlist the event does not get fired.

Comment: What is the `@Html.IdFor()` Helper you are using?

Comment: it's an html helper method i created to get the id that will be generated

Comment: link to an updated version of jqtransform http://pastebin.com/Q1pYMKZ2

Comment: @finnw: Just in case you read this (the answer got deleted so I cannot reply to you over there): The [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Q1pYMKZ2) contained almost 400 lines of code. Copying all of it into the answer would barely be helpful. And just mentioning an "updated version" is not really answering the question at all so it should be *converted to a comment*, which is a valid reason for a "not an answer" flag - and that's what actually happened.